# Flattening Dynamodb write bursts

Tags: caching, amazon-web-services, memcached, composer-php

I'm looking for a creative and most efficient way to flatten write bursts to dynamodb.

I have 4 cron jobs that run every 3 minutes .each on its own thread. due to reason I can't control they start at the same time. 
Part of the jobs is to write a few 1000s of rows to dynamodb. This takes normally 10 to 30 seconsa using batch writes.

Because of the timing the 4 jobs do the writing it in parallel.

I'm looking for the most efficient way to distribute the writes over time .

I don't want to add resources of not necessary. Probably the solution includes some kind of cache and additional cron job.

I have memcache available. However there is probably something more efficient than writing to memcache and reading . 
Maybe a log file on the server ?

What would you do?

It's php with apache on ububtu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An established pattern, especially if you just need the writes to get there eventually, is to put your records into an SQS queue first, and have a background task that reads messages from SQS and puts them into the dynamodb and a maximum prescribed rate - this is useful when you don't want to pay for the high write throughput to match your peak periods of writes to the database.

SQS has the benefit of being able to accept messages at almost any scale and yet you can reduce your dynamodb costs by writing rows at a low, predictable pace.

Comment: Thanks e.j. I will definitely check this option out.